# How to open phpmyadmin after xampp installed on linux?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed xampp on linux but I couldn't open phpmyadmin page.
I tried `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/`. Can you help me?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

Comment: And how have you installed `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: i use command.
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

Comment: You need to install `phpmyadmin` : `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`.

Comment: @hg8 : how to choose config to run phpmyadmin? apache2 or lighttpd

Comment: See my updated answer : Navigate with TAB and select `apache2` with SPACE **;-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the command

```
sudo apt-get install 'lamp-server^'
```

you have installed a thing called *task*. But this task does not contain `phpmyadmin`.

You have to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

---

At this step :

[image]

Do not forget to check `apache2` with <kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select **OK**.

Comment: It is not necessary to install phpmyadmin part form the XAMPP installation, see answer of @Error1x.

Answer (score 1):

In the opt/lampp folder, you can see a phpmyadmin folder.So the phpmyadmin is exactly to be installed.  Let's do the restart command again.
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start (if not start, please do it again.

And then, input http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ in you browser. It may work.

Comment: This is the solution when you have already installed XAMPP, because there is no need to install phpmyadmin apart as it is by default included in the XAMPP installation. Just run `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` or `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart` in your console before opening manually `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` in a new browser tab.